# Ionic 3 Segment ngAfterViewInit not working

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am trying to use Ionic 3 Segment on a page that fetches some data from a third party script, but Ionic3 or Angular4 is not binding the changes on the ionic-segment tag.

Ionic is not activating the selected button, nor is the ngSwitch working at all.

The third party library is sucessfully requested on ngOnInit() method, and the page is rendered, but with no events bound at all.

But when the code executes:

```
this.segment.ngAfterViewInit();
```

A TypeScript error is triggered:

```
Property 'ngAfterViewInit' does not exist on type 'Segment'.
```

Here is my Checkout page:

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Segment} from 'ionic-angular';
import {CartProvider} from "../../providers/cart/cart";

export class CheckoutPage implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild(Segment)
    segment: Segment;

    paymentMethod: string = "CREDIT_CARD";
    paymentMethods: Array<any> = new Array();

    creditCard = {
        num: '',
        cvv: '',
        monthExp: '',
        yearExp: '',
        brand: '',
        token: ''
    };

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                public navParams: NavParams,
                private cart: CartProvider,
                private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        PagSeguroDirectPayment.getPaymentMethods({
            amount: this.cart.total,
            success: response => {
                let paymentMethods = response.paymentMethods;
                this.paymentMethods = Object.keys(paymentMethods)
                    .map((key) => paymentMethods[key]);
                this.ref.detectChanges();
                this.segment.ngAfterViewInit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my checkout template:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>Checkout</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="paymentMethod">
        <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let p of paymentMethods" value="{{p.name}}">
            {{p.name}}
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
    <div [ngSwitch]="paymentMethod">
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'BOLETO'">
            <ion-card>
                <ion-card-header>
                    Total: <strong>{{cart.total}}</strong>
                </ion-card-header>
            </ion-card>
            <ion-card>
                <button ion-button>Generate</button>
            </ion-card>
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'CREDIT_CARD'">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Card Number</ion-label>
                    <ion-input type="text" value="" [(ngModel)]="creditCard.num"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>CVV</ion-label>
                    <ion-input type="text" value="" [(ngModel)]="creditCard.cvv"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Month</ion-label>
                    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="creditCard.monthExp"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Year</ion-label>
                    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="creditCard.yearExp"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
            <button (click)="runPayment()" ion-button>Pay</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let i of cart.items">
            {{i.name}} - R$ {{i.price}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button (click)="goToCheckout()" ion-button>Checkout</button>
</ion-content>
```

Here are my specifications:

```
Ionic Framework: 3.6.0
Ionic App Scripts: 2.1.3
Angular Core: 4.1.3
Angular Compiler CLI: 4.1.3
Node: 8.1.2
OS Platform: Windows 10
Navigator Platform: Win32
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
```

I am used to Ionic 2, and all that code run like a charm. 
No clue at all how to solve it!

Comment: Why do you call `this.segment.ngAfterViewInit();` ?

Comment: If not using .ngAfterViewInit(), the content won't be live for some reason I don't know! It worked for Ionic 2 / Angular 2, but doesn't work for Ionic 3 / Angular 4.

Comment: Could you please refer some document about that way? I have never seen `ngAfterViewInit` is used like that

Comment: @Duannx http://embed.plnkr.co/GyCLkQ0aFgFpPr9QUSiO/ Please visit the file "home.ts".

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ionViewDidLoad()` rather than `ngAfterViewInit()`

**Entering into the page view :**

1. ionViewCanEnter()
2. ionViewDidLoad()
3. ionViewWillEnter()
4. ionViewDidEnter()

**Exit from page view:**

5. ionViewWillLeave()
6. ionViewDidLeave

Answer (score 0):

Seem like `Segment` class has no more function `ngAfterViewInit()` now. Use `ngAfterContentInit()` instead. 
You can find what function and propertive in a class by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> to the class name